# C Programming — get multiple words in string

Tags: c, string, text, input, printing

I am trying to get a full sentence eg. "This is a sentence." to be stored in the global variable string named 'global'. It will then print out the sentence back out. However after entering my input, I can only get the first word of the sentence printed (This). Anyone got any ideas?

```
#include <string.h>

char** global;

int main () {

    printf("Please Enter Text: \n");
    scanf("%s", &global);

    printf("%s", &global);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ampersand(&) should not be there in `printf`

Comment: @ShashankKadne: without the `&`, `global` is still a pointer to a `char` pointer.  If it points at valid data structures, then `*global` would give a `char *` that could be printed with `%s`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `char** global` should be `char* global` only.

`&` with `printf` is not required.

You need to use `fgets(var_name,no_of_chars,FILE*)` in place of `scanf`.

```
fgets(global,100,stdin); //where global is char global[100];
```

Example :

**Use of `gets` is more serious then i was thinking. So it's no longer recommended.**

A Better one

```
char global[100];    
int main () {
    printf("Please Enter Text: \n");
    if(fgets(global,50,stdin)) //It will take Maximum 50 chars. So no buffer overflow. 
    fputs(global,stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if i enter multiple lines as input, the (unknown code) will only print first line. can do i fix that?

Comment: @NewFile: that is a new question, unrelated to the current one.

Comment: -1: Dammit: ***Never***, but never, recommend `gets()`. It is lethal. It is also no longer standard C (it was removed from the C11 standard). Always use either `fgets()` or (on a POSIX system) `getline()` or a similar function. You do have to deal with the newline with `fgets()`; that is a nuisance (and it might be a reason to write your own cover function for `fgets()` that removes it and, since it has the information, reports on the length of the string read). But don't ever use `gets()`, not even in toy code.

Comment: There's a secondary problem; you've only implicitly covered the fact that `char **global;` (or `char *global;`) is a null pointer; space must be allocated.  Your final 'if size is unknown' code has `&` that should not be present, and is misguided.  If you don't know how much space `global` points at, you have to do stuff like `if (global != 0 && (len = strlen(global) + 1) > 1) { if (fgets(global, len, stdin) != 0) fputs(global, stdout); }` using the length of the string that `global` points to as the (presumably) safe length.  Anything longer could be problematic.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Corrected! first point. I didn't understand your last comment. Without `&` it's not working.

Comment: My last comment is about: `char* global=0; int main() { printf("Please Enter Text: \n"); if (fgets(&global,101,stdin)) { fputs(&global,stdout); }`. (a) You don't have space allocated for `global` to point at. (b) You don't need the `&` in `fgets(&global, 101, stdin)` because you don't pass a `char **` to `fgets()` or `fputs()`. (c) You don't guess that `global` points at 101 characters.  You either know how much space it points at (nothing, but we've fixed that in point (a)), or you find the length of the string that it currently points at and assume that's all the space that's available.

Comment: Pure bad luck...You passed the address of global, so the string was written over the null pointer, and whatever else happened to be after it in memory.  It just so happened that it wasn't at the end of allocated memory, etc, so you trampled who knows what but you weren't using it so it didn't break.  That's one of the problems with undefined behaviour; sometimes things appear to work when there's no guarantee that they will work.

Comment: Downvote rescinded.  The answer has been improved considerably since I downvoted it (and improvement was the objective of the downvote).

Answer (score 3):

Your variable `char **global;` is a disaster zone.  It is a null pointer.  It must be made to point to some valid data before it can be used.  It is a double pointer, in fact, so you have to make space available like this:

```
char array[1000];
char *pointer = array;
char **global = &pointer;
```

Now you could safely use `global[0]`.

Inside the function, you pass `&global` to `scanf()`; that is a `char ***`.  Being a ['Three-Star Programmer'](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer) is not a good thing, especially when you do it by accident and not by design.

You include the header `<string.h>` but don't use any of its functions.  You do use functions from `<stdio.h>` and you don't include that.  Technically, you invoke undefined behaviour by using the variadic functions `printf()` and `scanf()` without a function prototype in scope.  The compiler is entitled to be told about functions that take a variable number of arguments (that's what 'variadic' means), and is entitled to miscompile code where it is not told that the function is variadic.

Assuming you really do need a global variable at all (they're generally not a good idea and you should avoid using them as much as possible), then you could reasonably write:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char global[1000];

int main(void)
{
    printf("Please Enter Text: ");
    if (scanf("%s", global) == 1)
        printf("%s\n", global);
    return 0;
}
```

This is at least sound code, but it still has your original problem that it reads only one word, not a whole line.

Forget that `gets()` exists.  It was one of the buggy functions used in the first Internet Worm of 1988 (Google for 'morris internet worm').  It is irredeemable; it cannot be used safely in a hostile environment, and all programming has to be done assuming a hostile environment.

To read a line, use `fgets()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char global[1000];

int main(void)
{
    printf("Please Enter Text: ");
    if (fgets(global, sizeof(global), stdin) != NULL)
    {
        size_t len = strlen(global);
        if (len != 0 && global[len-1] == '\n')
            global[--len] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", global);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This gets a line of data into `global`.

You can legitimately ask how `len` could ever be zero (I asked it of myself, and I replaced `assert(len != 0)` because of the answer). One answer would be 'standard input was redirected from a binary file and the first byte was a null (zero) byte'.  Then `fgets()` would read data including the null byte up to the first newline, but the `strlen()` would stop at the null byte, reporting 0 as the length.

The code removes the newline from the string, and determines its length at the same time — you normally need that length.  It then prints it.  Notice that the code checks that `fgets()` succeeded.  I/O (especially input) has a habit of breaking when you aren't looking.  A lot of the time, it will work fine, but to make your program robust, you have to be paranoid about input operations failing (and, later, memory allocations failing).

Comment: I note that the question asks about 'get a sentence' and not 'get a line'.  Treating it as meaning 'get more than one word into a string' allows this answer.  However, if you need a moderately strict definition of a sentence (a sequence of words ending with a full stop, exclamation mark or question mark, with complications like parentheses, quotes, and abbreviations to deal with), then this code is but a starting point, and not necessarily a good starting point.  For reading a 'real sentence', you'd probably be better off using character by character input, pushing back unwanted spaces etc.

Comment: Oh, and the `scanf()` code should really use `"%999s"` as the format string to ensure that `scanf()` does not overflow the variable.  Note the 'off-by-one' numbering; the length specified is the number of characters available excluding the null byte, hence the use of 999 when the buffer holds 1000 characters.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this:-

```
 scanf("%[^\t\n]",&global);
```

Also in your printf `&` is not required. It should be like:

```
printf("%s", global);
```

Comment: what does [^\t\n] mean?

Comment: @NewFile It is called scan set.

Comment: i got it working but i did &global instead of global, due to global gave me null as nothing is set by default in the global variable. Thanks

Comment: @NewFile:- Yes thats correct. I have updated my answer with that.! :)

Comment: This is because of the \n in your line!

Comment: @NewFile That's why i told you that it's scan set. the sole motive of this scan set it to read until \n is encountered.